# Find the extreme points of an integral function

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^x(t^3-3t+2)e^{t^2}dt$$
I have to find the extreme points of this x variable function. I tried to simply calculate the integral, however I get to the point where I have to calculate $ \int e^{t^2}$ which doesn't have elementary derivate and I dont have  another ideea to start with. Any thoughts?

Comment: When is the derivative equal to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we can find that point by solving:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\int_0^x e^{t^2}\left(t^3-3t+2\right)\space\text{d}t\right)=0\tag1$$

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\int_0^x e^{t^2}\left(t^3-3t+2\right)\space\text{d}t\right)
=e^{x^2}\left(x^3-3x+2\right)\tag2
$$

Now, solve:

$$e^{x^2}\left(x^3-3x+2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=-2\space\vee\space x=1\tag3$$

> So.....

Comment: What is $exp$? Extreme point?

Comment: @nakoomba No, $\exp\left(x\right):=e^x$.

Comment: I don t really understand how you got from $(1)$ to $(2)$...

Comment: By "Using the fundamental theorem of calculus".

Comment: But by using that isnt the derivate of the integral equal to $exp(x^2)(x^3-3x+2) - 2$?

Comment: @nakoomba No, why should it be?

Comment: Im thinking about Leibniz-Newton. Isn't that what you are using? If no, then I don't think I learned something(The fundamental theorem of calculus) helping me to understand that...

Comment: @nakoomba, in general, we know that $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\int_0^x\text{y}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right)=\text{y}\left(x\right)$$. For more information look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: Yea, I read about that, but I dont think I've learned that în class, therefore I can't really use it..

Comment: @nakoomba If you learned optimization and integration, I think you also learned the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: You are right, I searched for it in my notebook and I found it. Thank you!

Comment: @nakoomba You're welcome, you can accept my answer using the V sign next to my answer.